# How to display the link that says "Edit Header Image" on header image

Tags: custom-header, options, header-image

I have a website which featured with WP custom header image without plugin. I would like to ask that, is it possible to display a text with link which allows website owner easily change the header image by clicking the link instead of changing the header image in the admin panel?

For example, when you are in your Facebook account, your mouse over the profile picture, there will be a text with link "Update Profile Picture". I am looking for that kind of solution. Is it possible to make it happen in Wordpress platform?

Any suggestion?

Comment: Post what you have tried and investigate to make it at your own so we can help.

Comment: I should be able to get it work with my own way. =)